# What does a "b" mean in firebug release?

Tags: firebug

In the firebug release [downloads](http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.8/) there are many different choices. Many versions have an a or b appended to the name.  What does this mean?

For example:

firebug-1.8.0 **a3** .xpi

or

firebug-1.8.4 **b1** .xpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are alpha and beta versions.

Normally, it is a good idea to stick to the stable releases.